# Exporting the contents of an attribute table in formats other than an Excel file

Tags: arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, export

I know that it's possible to export the contents of an attribute table to an Excel file, but could they be exported in any other format (from ArcGIS 10.0)? I have a feature class whose attribute table (minus a few fields) needs to be made available to be displayed and read by the human eye as an ordinary table. Could the attribute table be exported into (for example) .pdf format, or do I have to export it to Excel first, and start from there?

Comment: What software are you exporting from?

Comment: Why is a pdf file more human readable than an excel file? I would argue the opposite.

Comment: I'm exporting from ArcGIS 10.0. If there is no better way, I will simply export it to Excel.

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean by 'read by the human eye as an ordinary table' Do you mean something that can be read without using special software? Would a CSV meet that criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using ArcGIS 10.0 you have access to the built-in reporting engine that will allow you to create and export reports from your data.  The reporting engine will allow you to select the fields that you want included in the report, as well as group and sort options, layout theme, etc.  And, you can export the reports to .pdf and a few other formats.  The reporting engine would work if the consumer of the report doesn't need to manipulate the data in any way.

See the following help items:

[What's new for reporting in ArcGIS 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00qp0000000s000000.htm)

[What are reports in ArcGIS?](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004v00000001000000.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In a short answer, No. The only options for export are tabular formats: DBF file, Text file (a CSV), or Geodatabase table. Your best option is to export it to text, open that in Excel, make it pretty, then print to PDF.

If your attribute table is small, you could perform a screen capture (`ALT+Print Screen` in Windows), then paste it into PowerPoint or a graphics program (e.g. Gimp, PhotoShop, MS Paint) and print it or save it as an image.

Answer (score 0):

By "read by human eyes", I meant, essentially, an easy-to-read printable version. I'll try the built-in reporting engine. Thanks, Timothy Michael. The question is answered.